# WooCommerce export CSV file

Tags: field, export-to-csv, woocommerce

I am interested in purchasing the order/customer CSV reports exporter add-on from WooCommerce.

Can anyone please tell me what fields are generated in the file once its been exported and are these editable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have some options when exporting orders. You can export with all items inside one column, or with each item on its own row. You can filter by date range for the export, and you can select which order statuses you would like to export via checkboxes.

If you export orders with each item on its own row, you have the following columns:

> Order ID, Date, Order Status, Shipping, Shipping Tax, Tax, Cart
>   Discount, Order Discount, Order Total,    Payment Method, Shipping
>   Method,   Billing First Name, Billing Last Name,  Billing Email,  Billing
>   Phone,    Billing Address 1,  Billing Address 2,  Billing Post
>   code, Billing City,   Billing State,  Billing Country,    Billing
>   Company,  Shipping First Name,    Shipping Last Name, Shipping Address
>   1,    Shipping Address 2, Shipping Post code, Shipping City,  Shipping
>   State,    Shipping Country,   Shipping Company,   Customer Note,  Item
>   SKU,  Item Name,  Item Variation, Item Amount,    Row Price

If you export clients, you get the following columns:

> ID,   First Name, Last Name,  Email,  Phone,  Address,    Address 2,  Post
>   code, City,   State,  Country,    Company

They do export as a CSV files so you can edit them with a program like Microsoft Excel.